# Finding available LPT (parallel) ports and addresses in Delphi

Tags: delphi, port, parallel-processing, pci-bus, lpt

I am doing direct I/O on a parallel port which is fine and necessary for speed. I would like to enumerate the available ports to offer the user a choice of ports at setup time rather than a tedious trawl through device manager to read the address manually. Does anyone know a means of doing this please?
Many thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 2):

According to [this Microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa506006.aspx), for Win2K and newer, you can find details of parallel-connected devices in the registry at HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\LPTENUM.