# Listing serial (COM) ports on Windows?

Tags: python, c, windows, winapi, serial-port

I'm looking for a robust way to list the available serial (COM) ports on a Windows machine. There's [this post about using WMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081871/how-to-find-available-com-ports), but I would like something less .NET specific - I want to get the list of ports in a Python or a C++ program, without .NET.

I currently know of two other approaches:

1. Reading the information in the `HARDWARE\\DEVICEMAP\\SERIALCOMM` registry key. This looks like a great option, but is it **robust**? I can't find a guarantee online or in MSDN that this registry cell indeed always holds the full list of available ports.
2. Tryint to call `CreateFile` on `COMN` with N a number from 1 to something. This isn't good enough, because some COM ports aren't named COMN. For example, some virtual COM ports created are named CSNA0, CSNB0, and so on, so I wouldn't rely on this method.

Any other methods/ideas/experience to share?

**Edit:** by the way, here's a simple Python implementation of reading the port names from registry:

```
import _winreg as winreg
import itertools


def enumerate_serial_ports():
    """ Uses the Win32 registry to return a iterator of serial 
        (COM) ports existing on this computer.


    """
    path = 'HARDWARE\\DEVICEMAP\\SERIALCOMM'
    try:
        key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, path)
    except WindowsError:
        raise IterationError

    for i in itertools.count():
        try:
            val = winreg.EnumValue(key, i)
            yield (str(val[1]), str(val[0]))
        except EnvironmentError:
            break
```

Comment: Looks very useful to find com ports - I'm going to try and use it to find Arduino port

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Several options are available:

1. Call [QueryDosDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365461(VS.85).aspx) with a NULL lpDeviceName to list all DOS devices. Then use CreateFile and [GetCommConfig](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363256(VS.85).aspx) with each device name in turn to figure out whether it's a serial port.
2. Call [SetupDiGetClassDevs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms792959.aspx) with a ClassGuid of GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT.
3. [WMI is also available to C/C++ programs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389762(VS.85).aspx).

There's some conversation on the [win32 newsgroup](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.kernel/browse_thread/thread/9c1bb578bd9cb309) and a CodeProject, er, [project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/setupdi.aspx).

Comment: Trying to use QueryDosDevice, but having trouble to know which devices are serial ports. GetCommConfig isn't part of Pywin32 for some reason

Comment: I've been impressed at how well [Teraterm](http://logmett.com/index.php?/products/teraterm.html) lists serial ports. I looked in the source code, and it turns out, `ListupSerialPort()` in [`ttcmn.c`](http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/ttssh2/svn/view/trunk/teraterm/ttpcmn/ttcmn.c?view=markup&root=ttssh2) refers to [that CodeProject project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2609/Enumerating-serial-ports-W2K-style).

Answer (score 36):

Using pySerial with Python:

```
import serial.tools.list_ports


ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
for p in ports:
    print p
```

Comment: Or directly from command line, `python -m serial.tools.list_ports`

Comment: Make sure to put parentheses around the p

Answer (score 6):

The PySerial project provides a [couple of solutions](http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html).

Comment: This is a relatively new feature for Pyserial but should be the correct solution going forward.

Answer (score 5):

I just created the following, based on reading through the C++ source to [EnumSerialPorts](http://www.naughter.com/enumser.html) and seeing the function `GetDefaultCommConfig()`.  It looked like the simplest method using simple ANSI C and a single API call for each possible COM port.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winbase.h>

BOOL COM_exists( int port)
{
    char buffer[7];
    COMMCONFIG CommConfig;
    DWORD size;

    if (! (1 <= port && port <= 255))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    snprintf( buffer, sizeof buffer, "COM%d", port);
    size = sizeof CommConfig;

    // COM port exists if GetDefaultCommConfig returns TRUE
    // or changes <size> to indicate COMMCONFIG buffer too small.
    return (GetDefaultCommConfig( buffer, &CommConfig, &size)
                                                    || size > sizeof CommConfig);
}

int main()
{
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i < 256; ++i)
    {
        if (COM_exists( i))
        {
            printf( "COM%d exists\n", i);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Nowadays there's a Powershell one-liner for that.

```
[System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::GetPortNames()
```

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely fairly late, but it proved helpful to me!

http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/07/31/listing-all-serial-ports-on-windows-with-python/

Particularly this example:

```
import re

def full_port_name(portname):
    """ Given a port-name (of the form COM7,
        COM12, CNCA0, etc.) returns a full
        name suitable for opening with the
        Serial class.
    """
    m = re.match('^COM(\d+)$', portname)
    if m and int(m.group(1)) < 10:
    return portname
return '\\\\.\\' + portname
```

Comment: No worries, it was fun to see :-)

Answer (score 2):

There's an example in the pyserial distro now that does this called scanwin32.py

http://pyserial.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.5/scanwin32_8py_source.html

Answer (score 2):

I think WMI is the way to go since it's pretty easy to get going and it has minimal code. It saves you from having to dig inside the registry and gives you some guarantee that it will work for more general situations in the future.

You can install everything needed with `pip install pypiwin32 WMI` and it works out-of-the-box.

**Code**

```
import wmi

query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE Name LIKE '%(COM%)'"
coms  = wmi.WMI().query(query)

for com in coms:
    print(com.Name)
```

**Output**

```
Communications Port (COM1)
mbed Serial Port (COM3)
mbed Serial Port (COM5)
```

My guess is that your serial port is some sort of Plug 'n Play so this should work fine. For some reason `Win32_SerialPort` doesn't work for all ports.