# Serial port enumeration in Delphi using SetupDiGetClassDevs

Tags: delphi, serial-port, enumerate

I'm trying to enumerate "friendly names" for COM ports. The ports may dynamically change as USB-serial devices are connected and disconnected at runtime.

Based on the possible methods described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205383/listing-serial-com-ports-on-windows/3018813#3018813), I am attempting to use the SetupDiGetClassDevs method.

I found [this example code](http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_4001.asp?SK=), but it is written for an older version of the setupapi unit (the original link to homepages.borland.com doesn't work of course).

I tried using the setupapi unit from the current JVCL([JVCL340CompleteJCL221-Build3845](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jvcl/files/JVCL%203/JVCL%203.40/JVCL340CompleteJCL221-Build3845.zip/download)), but it doesn't seem to be compatible with Delphi 7. I get compiler errors:

```
if SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(DevInfoHandle,DeviceInfoData,
    RegProperty,
    @PropertyRegDataType,
    @S1[1],RequiredSize,@RequiredSize) then begin
```

In the call to function *SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty*,
I get the error "Types of actual and formal parameters must be identical" on the parameters *@PropertyRegDataType*, and *@RequiredSize*.

The Delphi3000 site says the code was written in 2004 and is intended for Delphi 7, so I'm not sure why it doesn't work with Delphi 7 now, unless setupapi has changed. Is anyone familiar with the changes to setupapi that could cause these problems?

I'm testing with a simple console program. The uses statement is "  windows,
  sysutils,
  classes,
  setupAPI,
  Registry;"

The main program is:

```
  begin
  ComPortStringList := SetupEnumAvailableComPorts;
  for Index := 0 to ComPortStringList.Count - 1 do
      writeln(ComPortStringList[Index]);
  end;
  end.
```

Comment: The link to the example code in this question is now obsolete (Sep 2020). See the answer from `Grzegorz Skoczylas` which works with Delphi 7 on Windows 10 (and works with both in-built and USB-to-serial adapter COM ports).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like some arguments of type `PDWord` were replaced by `var DWord` in `SetupApi.pas`. All you need is to remove '@' from these arguments in your code like that:

```
if SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(DevInfoHandle,DeviceInfoData,
                                    RegProperty,
                                    PropertyRegDataType,
                                    @S1[1],RequiredSize,RequiredSize) then begin
```

Answer (score 11):

The following procedure is working correctly for me (in Windows 8.1). It is important to use the parameter `KEY_READ` in the `TRegistry.Constructor`.

```
procedure  EnumComPorts(const   Ports:  TStringList);

var
  nInd:  Integer;

begin  { EnumComPorts }
  with  TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ)  do
    try
      RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
      if  OpenKey('hardware\devicemap\serialcomm', False)  then
        try
          Ports.BeginUpdate();
          try
            GetValueNames(Ports);
            for  nInd := Ports.Count - 1  downto  0  do
              Ports.Strings[nInd] := ReadString(Ports.Strings[nInd]);
            Ports.Sort()
          finally
            Ports.EndUpdate()
          end { try-finally }
        finally
          CloseKey()
        end { try-finally }
      else
        Ports.Clear()
    finally
      Free()
    end { try-finally }
end { EnumComPorts };
```

Comment: This procedure should work correctly in Windows 10 alse, but I didn't checked it yet.

Comment: Works also in Windows 7

Comment: While I haven't tested this yet, I'm manually looking at Windows 10 Regedit, and I don't see a `serialcom` key under `devicemap`.

Comment: This procedure works for me for years. It works in Windows 7, 8 and 10. Currently I have Windows 10 Pro.

Are you sure you checked it in the branch HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE?

Comment: Can confirm with @GrzegorzSkoczylas that this works on Windows 10. Note that the key is `SERIALCOMM`, not `SERIALCOM` (ie. two "m"s).

Comment: If anything Ports should be passed by var no by const.

Comment: This didn't work on Windows 10 20H2. There is no key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\hardware\devicemap\serialcomm

Answer (score 7):

I was able to get some more specific suggestions by [asking the question a different way with different tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004854/windows-api-parameters-in-delphi-passing-var-parameter-with-or-without-operat).

It turns out there were errors in the delphi3000.com example code, and possibly errors in the JVCL code. After fixing the example code errors, I got it to work. I have not addressed the potential JVCL errors.

Here is the working code (as a simple console app) for enumerating the names of com ports:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
program EnumComPortsTest;


uses
  windows,
  sysutils,
  classes,
  setupAPI,
  Registry;

{$R *.RES}

var
   ComPortStringList : TStringList;

(*

The function below returns a list of available COM-ports
(not open by this or an other process), with friendly names. The list is formatted as follows:

COM1: = Communications Port (COM1)
COM5: = NI Serial Port (Com5)
COM6: = NI Serial Port (Com6)
COM7: = USB Serial Port (COM7)
COM8: = Bluetooth Communications Port (COM8)
COM9: = Bluetooth Communications Port (COM9)

This code originally posted at http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_4001.asp?SK=
errors have been fixed so it will work with Delphi 7 and SetupAPI from JVCL
*)

function SetupEnumAvailableComPorts:TstringList;
// Enumerates all serial communications ports that are available and ready to
// be used.

// For the setupapi unit see
// http://homepages.borland.com/jedi/cms/modules/apilib/visit.php?cid=4&lid=3

var
  RequiredSize:             Cardinal;
  GUIDSize:                 DWORD;
  Guid:                     TGUID;
  DevInfoHandle:            HDEVINFO;
  DeviceInfoData:           TSPDevInfoData;
  MemberIndex:              Cardinal;
  PropertyRegDataType:      DWord;
  RegProperty:              Cardinal;
  RegTyp:                   Cardinal;
  Key:                      Hkey;
  Info:                     TRegKeyInfo;
  S1,S2:                    string;
  hc:                       THandle;
begin
  Result:=Nil;
//If we cannot access the setupapi.dll then we return a nil pointer.
  if not LoadsetupAPI then exit;
  try
// get 'Ports' class guid from name

    GUIDSize := 1;    // missing from original code - need to tell function that the Guid structure contains a single GUID
    if SetupDiClassGuidsFromName('Ports',@Guid,GUIDSize,RequiredSize) then begin
//get object handle of 'Ports' class to interate all devices
       DevInfoHandle:=SetupDiGetClassDevs(@Guid,Nil,0,DIGCF_PRESENT);
       if Cardinal(DevInfoHandle)<>Invalid_Handle_Value then begin
         try
           MemberIndex:=0;
           result:=TStringList.Create;
//iterate device list
           repeat
             FillChar(DeviceInfoData,SizeOf(DeviceInfoData),0);
             DeviceInfoData.cbSize:=SizeOf(DeviceInfoData);
//get device info that corresponds to the next memberindex
             if Not SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(DevInfoHandle,MemberIndex,DeviceInfoData) then
               break;
//query friendly device name LIKE 'BlueTooth Communication Port (COM8)' etc
             RegProperty:=SPDRP_FriendlyName;{SPDRP_Driver, SPDRP_SERVICE, SPDRP_ENUMERATOR_NAME,SPDRP_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_OBJECT_NAME,SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME,}

             SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(DevInfoHandle,
                                                   DeviceInfoData,
                                                   RegProperty,
                                                   PropertyRegDataType,
                                                   NIL,0,RequiredSize);
             SetLength(S1,RequiredSize);

             if SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(DevInfoHandle,DeviceInfoData,
                                                 RegProperty,
                                                 PropertyRegDataType,
                                                 @S1[1],RequiredSize,RequiredSize) then begin
               KEY:=SetupDiOpenDevRegKey(DevInfoHandle,DeviceInfoData,DICS_FLAG_GLOBAL,0,DIREG_DEV,KEY_READ);
               if key<>INValid_Handle_Value then begin
                 FillChar(Info, SizeOf(Info), 0);
//query the real port name from the registry value 'PortName'
                 if RegQueryInfoKey(Key, nil, nil, nil, @Info.NumSubKeys,@Info.MaxSubKeyLen, nil, @Info.NumValues, @Info.MaxValueLen,
                                                        @Info.MaxDataLen, nil, @Info.FileTime) = ERROR_SUCCESS then begin
                   RequiredSize:= Info.MaxValueLen + 1;
                   SetLength(S2,RequiredSize);
                   if RegQueryValueEx(KEY,'PortName',Nil,@Regtyp,@s2[1],@RequiredSize)=Error_Success then begin
                     If (Pos('COM',S2)=1) then begin
//Test if the device can be used
                       hc:=CreateFile(pchar('\\.\'+S2+#0),
                                      GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE,
                                      0,
                                      nil,
                                      OPEN_EXISTING,
                                      FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                                      0);
                       if hc<> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then begin
                         Result.Add(Strpas(PChar(S2))+': = '+StrPas(PChar(S1)));
                         CloseHandle(hc);
                       end;
                     end;
                   end;
                 end;
                 RegCloseKey(key);
               end;
             end;
             Inc(MemberIndex);
           until False;
//If we did not found any free com. port we return a NIL pointer.
           if Result.Count=0 then begin
             Result.Free;
             Result:=NIL;

           end
         finally
           SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(DevInfoHandle);
         end;
       end;
    end;
  finally
    UnloadSetupApi;
  end;
end;



var
   index : integer;

begin

  ComPortStringList := SetupEnumAvailableComPorts;

  if (ComPortStringList <> nil) and (ComPortStringList.Count > 0) then
    for Index := 0 to ComPortStringList.Count - 1 do
      writeln(ComPortStringList[Index]);

end.
```

Comment: In this code SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo() always returns false.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have "typed @ operator" turned on? Project options, Compiler tab under "Syntax options". A lot of third party code breaks if that option is enabled.

Comment: The "Typed @ operator" option is not checked for this project. I already added {$VARSTRINGCHECKS OFF} around the call which fixed an error on @S1[1].   Can you think of anything else that could be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

For easier operation you might consider simply using the registry where those names are listed eg:

```
  ErrCode := RegOpenKeyEx(
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    'HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM',
    0,
    KEY_READ,
    KeyHandle);
```

(I've ommited the hand-waving stuff).

You might also consider using WMI - see [this example](http://www.magsys.co.uk/delphi/magwmi.asp) from Magenta Systems - you can get a pretty much everything hardware-related now.

Answer (score 0):

I adapted below code from RRUZ [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8519658/576719) for Serial Port class. Works fine under Win10 20H2.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj,
  Variants;


procedure  GetWin32_SerialPortInfo;
const
  WbemUser            ='';
  WbemPassword        ='';
  WbemComputer        ='localhost';
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;
begin;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(WbemComputer, 'root\CIMV2', WbemUser, WbemPassword);
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_SerialPort','WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 do
  begin
    // for other fields: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-serialport
    Writeln(Format('DeviceID        %s',[String(FWbemObject.DeviceID)]));// String
    Writeln(Format('Name            %s',[String(FWbemObject.Name)]));// String
    Writeln(Format('Description     %s',[String(FWbemObject.Description)]));// String
    FWbemObject:=Unassigned;
  end;
end;


begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      GetWin32_SerialPortInfo;
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```

Output:

```
DeviceID        COM7
Name            Silicon Labs CP210x USB to UART Bridge (COM7)
Description     Silicon Labs CP210x USB to UART Bridge
Press Enter to exit
```