# Windows API Parameters in Delphi - passing var parameter with or without @ operator?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, delphi-7

I'm trying to use a function that calls [SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff551967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with Delphi 7. 
The call is from the example function [SetupEnumAvailableComPorts](http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_4001.asp?SK=). It looks like this:

```
SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(
  DevInfoHandle,
  DeviceInfoData,
  RegProperty,
  @PropertyRegDataType,
  nil,
  0,
  @RequiredSize
);
```

I get the error "Types of actual and formal parameters must be identical" on the parameters @PropertyRegDataType, and @RequiredSize. These parameters are declared:

```
var
  RequiredSize: Cardinal;
  PropertyRegDataType: DWORD;
```

MSDN describes these parameters as: *"RequiredSize [out, optional] A pointer to a variable of type DWORD that receives the required size, in bytes, of the PropertyBuffer buffer that is required to hold the data for the requested property. This parameter is optional and can be NULL.*" and *"PropertyRegDataType [out, optional] A pointer to a variable that receives the data type of the property that is being retrieved. This is one of the standard registry data types. This parameter is optional and can be NULL."*

The declaration of SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty (in SetupAPI.pas from [JVCL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jvcl/files/JVCL%203/JVCL%203.40/JVCL340CompleteJCL221-Build3845.zip/download)) looks like:

```
function SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(
  DeviceInfoSet: HDEVINFO;
  const DeviceInfoData: TSPDevInfoData; 
  Property_: DWORD;
  var PropertyRegDataType: DWORD; 
  PropertyBuffer: PBYTE; 
  PropertyBufferSize: DWORD;
  var RequiredSize: DWORD
): BOOL; stdcall; {$EXTERNALSYM SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty}
```

Since PropertyRegDataType and RequiredSize are var parameters, they should be able to be passed without the @ operator. In fact, if I remove the @ operators from the function call parameters, the code compiles, but crashes with an access violation (read of address 0). The [original code](http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_4001.asp?SK=) was written for Delphi 7, so why would they use the @ operator on these parameters? What am I missing?

Comment: You should report this issue to JEDI's WINAPI team, because `var` modifier violates `optional` clause in function contract (it is still possible to pass `nil` but using rather dirty hack)

Comment: Are you sure the code really compiled in Delphi 7? It's not unheard of for people to publish code that doesn't compile. Also consider that the Jedi code could have changed during the six years since your code was published. Besides, the Jedi declaration is wrong — pointer parameters that are allowed to be null should always be declared as pointers in Delphi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your variables `PropertyRegDataType` and `RequiredSize` should be declared as `DWORD`. You actually declare `RequiredSize` as `Cardinal` although that is equivalent.

You are correct that since they are `var` parameters you should not include the `@` address operator.

It's hard to say why you are getting the error message without actually knowing what you pass for the other parameters.

**EDIT**

As commentators have pointed out, the JEDI translation is incorrect and `PropertyRegDataType`, because it is an optional parameter, should be passed by value and typed as `PDWORD` so that you are able to pass `nil`.

Comment: Thanks - I got it working. The example on delphi3000.com has multiple errors. After removing the @ address operators, I debugged the crash, which was at a different point. There was a call to SetupDiClassGuidsFromName with an uninitialized value for ClassGuidListSize.

Comment: I'll post the working function on my original questions that was on the topic of com-port enumeration rather than passing parameters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999964/serial-port-enumeration-in-delphi-using-setupdigetclassdevs

Answer (score 4):

Delphi supports "reference parameters" via the `var` and `out` keywords and in some API conversions, the C-like pointers may be replaced by this convention; these paremeters are mandatory and must be passed as-is, w/o the address operator `@`.
If the parameter declaration is left as pointer, allowing you to pass `nil`, you *have to* ensure the parameter is optional -or- set it to valid memory memory location of appropriate size via the `@` operator; *no typechecking is performed in this case*.

Comment: Type checking is performed if you switch `$TYPEDADDRESS` on

Comment: Which you can't do if a variable-sized buffer is expected, as in this case, cause Delphis' `PByte` is "pointer to a single byte", and *not* C-like "pointer to the start of a byte array".

Comment: @Viktor Well you can if you have an array of bytes. You just return the address of the first one. In this case though it seems just to be a void pointer. It's more common in the Win32 API for these optional parameters to be pointers to single structs in which case `$TYPEDADDRESS` does result in static type safety.

Comment: @David I know what you mean, and I agree that `$TYPEDADDRESS` gives you some additional type safety. I only want to point out that it may not be desireable in some cases, including this question. Also, interpreting array of byte as `PByte` will result in an ocean of pain if you ever try to refactor to dynamic arrays :)

Comment: @Viktor OK. By the way, I wasn't meaning to criticise, only to clarify and (hopefully) add some helpful commentary!

Comment: @David I appreciate the clarification as I completely forgot about the possible use of `$TYPEDADDRESS` as I answered the question :)