# Error with variables/procedure

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

```
procedure  GetWin32_DiskDriveInfo;
const
  WbemUser            ='';
  WbemPassword        ='';
  WbemComputer        ='localhost';
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : Variant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  sValue        : string;
begin  
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(WbemComputer, 'root\CIMV2', WbemUser, WbemPassword);
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive','WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, nil) = 0 do
```

so I'm having **[dcc32 Error] Project2.dpr(29): E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical** . I'm having it on the last line of the code shown above (I suppose It has something to do with FWbemObject) variable .
Nota that I use Delphi 10 Seattle .

Comment: Do you understand what the error means?

Comment: I read http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/cm_var_type_conflict_xml.html and I'm pretty sure I understand but I can't seem to be able to fix it .

Comment: Source is taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519658/how-to-call-a-list-of-the-physically-attached-hard-disks-using-free-pascal-or which makes me even wonder why it's not working for me if it's working for the OP.

Comment: @ImadLekal, code is for fpc, use this instead: [wmi-delphi-code-creator](https://github.com/RRUZ/wmi-delphi-code-creator/wiki/DelphiDevelopers).

Answer (score 4):

The code that you are using if for FPC, under Delphi you need make a few changes.

This how the `IEnumVARIANT.Next` function is defined

```
function Next(celt: LongWord; var rgvar : OleVariant; out pceltFetched: LongWord): HResult; stdcall;
```

So you need change the type of `FWbemObject` to OleVariant and add another variable for the `pceltFetched` param.

Like so

```
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  pceltFetched  :  LongWord;
begin
  ...
  ...
  while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, pceltFetched) = 0 do
  ...
  ...

 end;
```

Also if you want use this code from a console App remember call to the `CoInitialize` method.

Answer (score 3):

That routine requires a few changes for Seattle - see below.

The second Param to oEnum.Next should be an OleVariant, and the third, a LongWord.  Also, you need to call CoInitialize/CoUnitialize

```
procedure  GetWin32_DiskDriveInfo;
const
  WbemUser            ='';
  WbemPassword        ='';
  WbemComputer        ='localhost';
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OleVariant;  //   NOT Variant
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  sValue        : string;
  Fetched : LongWord;  // Added, required 3rd Param to oEnum.Next
begin;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(WbemComputer, 'root\CIMV2', WbemUser, WbemPassword);
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive','WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, Fetched) = 0 do
  begin
    sValue:= FWbemObject.Properties_.Item('Caption').Value;
    Writeln(Format('Caption        %s',[sValue]));// String
    sValue:= FWbemObject.Properties_.Item('DeviceID').Value;
    Writeln(Format('DeviceID       %s',[sValue]));// String
    sValue:= FWbemObject.Properties_.Item('Model').Value;
    Writeln(Format('Model          %s',[sValue]));// String
    sValue:= FWbemObject.Properties_.Item('Partitions').Value;
    Writeln(Format('Partitions     %s',[sValue]));// Uint32
    sValue:= FWbemObject.Properties_.Item('PNPDeviceID').Value;
    Writeln(Format('PNPDeviceID    %s',[sValue]));// String
    sValue:= FormatFloat('#,', FWbemObject.Properties_.Item('Size').Value / (1024*1024));
    Writeln(Format('Size           %s mb',[sValue]));// Uint64

    Writeln;
    FWbemObject:= Unassigned;
  end;
end;

begin
  CoInitialize(Nil);  // Added

  try
    GetWin32_DiskDriveInfo;
  except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
  end;
  Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
  Readln;
  CoUnInitialize;  //Added
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you used from RRUZ [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8519658/576719) is for fpc.

Use this [link](https://github.com/RRUZ/wmi-delphi-code-creator/wiki/DelphiDevelopers), and this code for Delphi:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj,
  Variants;



// The Win32_DiskDrive class represents a physical disk drive as seen by a computer running the Win32 operating system. Any interface to a Win32 physical disk drive is a descendent (or member) of this class. The features of the disk drive seen through this object correspond to the logical and management characteristics of the drive. In some cases, this may not reflect the actual physical characteristics of the device. Any object based on another logical device would not be a member of this class.
// Example: IDE Fixed Disk.

procedure  GetWin32_DiskDriveInfo;
const
  WbemUser            ='';
  WbemPassword        ='';
  WbemComputer        ='localhost';
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;
begin;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(WbemComputer, 'root\CIMV2', WbemUser, WbemPassword);
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive','WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 do
  begin
    Writeln(Format('DeviceID    %s',[String(FWbemObject.DeviceID)]));// String

    Writeln('');
    FWbemObject:=Unassigned;
  end;
end;


begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      GetWin32_DiskDriveInfo;
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode])); 
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;      
end.
```