# how to find all serial devices ? (COM*)

Tags: python, windows

I want to discover all serial devices on my Windows PC, via a Python script.
How can I achieve this properly ?

The ugly way is to try opening COM1, COM2, ..., COM9999 (what is the limit ?), and when an exception is raised, then conclude that no device is there.

Comment: I found [this](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html)

Comment: and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090503/listing-available-com-ports-with-python

Comment: These links are interesting. They do not give any answer but refer to other interesting information. I will try something tomorrow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer that uses the pyserial module, though it is not documented:

```
import serial.tools.list_ports_windows
devices = serial.tools.list_ports_windows.comports()
```

and on Linux (though not addressed in the original question):

```
import serial.tools.list_ports_posix
devices = serial.tools.list_ports_posix.comports()
```