# Redetect Arduino board in Python program

Tags: python, tkinter, serial-port, arduino

For my program, I need to detect an Arduino board once it has been disconnected then reconnected, during the run of my program. I have perfectly detected the disconnection, but when reconnect the board, the program doesn't deal with it.

I tried to make this code for that (this is an UI, and I need to communicate about the connection state of the board) :

```
def update(self):
    try:
            ser.write('P')
            time.sleep(0.1)
            if ser.read() == "V":
                    self.photo=PhotoImage(file ='buttongreen.gif')
            else:
                    self.photo=PhotoImage(file ='buttonred.gif')
                    ser.close()
    except:
            try:
                    ser.open()
                    if ser.read() == "V":
                            self.photo=PhotoImage(file ='buttongreen.gif')
                    else:
                            self.photo=PhotoImage(file ='buttonred.gif')
            except:
                    self.photo=PhotoImage(file ='buttonred.gif')

pic = Canvas(self,width =64, height = 64, bg ='blue')
pic.grid(row=1, columnspan=3,column=1,padx = 10, pady =10)
pic.create_image(34,34, image=self.photo)
```

Is it possible to solve this problem and how do that? Thanks!

Edit : I'm working with Tkinter, Python 2.7 and an Arduino Uno and Leornardo

Comment: I guess `ser` is the serial, which library do you use? Under which OS?

Comment: I use serial, time and Tkinter libraries in the rest of the code, with Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do is:

1. [list all ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090503/listing-available-com-ports-with-python)
2. if the list is not empty, create a new serial connection

[Works for me](https://github.com/niccokunzmann/Arduino-Monitor)

Does this meet your expectation?

Never write `try: except:` by the way. Always say what you are catching.

Comment: Yes, it is what I expected, now I have to work for adapting it to my code, Thanks! ;)