# Make Arduinos stay on the same com<x> when using USB

Tags: python, arduino, arduino-uno

Every time I plug in an Arduino Uno on my computer, I need to change the code (Python, pyfirmata library) to connect to a different "COM{n}" port. I would like to be able to have a piece of code that will always be able to connect to an Arduino when it is connected via USB. The piece of code that I use to establish connection to the Arduino is as follows:

```
self.board = pyfirmata.Arduino("COM4")
```

The parameter of the function is what always changes if I change Arduino. It could change to "COM7" for example, randomly. Is there a solution to this, so I can always connect to the Arduino, and not have to change the COM port all the time manually?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python to automatically select serial ports (for Arduino)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214643/python-to-automatically-select-serial-ports-for-arduino)

Comment: Assigning USB Serial ports to `COM<n>` names is done by the operating system. Rather check there, why the previously assigned name is still blocked (?) when replugging the same Arduino?

Comment: Did my answer help you? Accept it

Answer (score 1):

Module `pyfirmata` has method `get_the_board()` in `util.py` ([link](https://github.com/tino/pyFirmata/blob/master/pyfirmata/util.py))

> Helper function to get the one and only board connected to the computer
>   running this. It assumes a normal arduino layout, but this can be
>   overriden by passing a different layout dict as the `layout` parameter.
>   `base_dir` and `identifier` are overridable as well. It will raise an
>   IOError if it can't find a board, on a serial, or if it finds more than one.

In addition, see [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214643/python-to-automatically-select-serial-ports-for-arduino) with implemented methods by other users.