# "Resource busy" error when connecting to USB port

Tags: python, serial-port, usb, sensors

I have code that attempts to connect to a USB ECG sensor device for continuous data streaming:

```
import serial 

s = serial.Serial()
s.port = "/dev/tty.my-device"
s.open()
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "create_port.py", line 7, in <module>
    s.open()
  File "/Users/dimachy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 289, in open
  self.fd = os.open(self.portstr, os.O_RDWR|os.O_NOCTTY|os.O_NONBLOCK)
OSError: [Errno 16] Resource busy: '/dev/tty.my-device'
```

I have tried running above code with sudo without success. I've tried making the the USB service inactive in network preferences on my computer, which also didn't change above error.

When I scan for available ports using code from Thomas's answer here:

[Listing available com ports with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090503/listing-available-com-ports-with-python)

I find that only one port is available, which is listed as a bluetooth port. The /dev/tty.my-device port does not appear in this scan.

When the ECG device is plugged in via USB it starts transmitting data immediately (no call to device is needed to get it to start). I'm guessing this may have something to do with the "Resource busy" error I'm getting above.

I'm very new to network programming so I'm probably missing something obvious. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to see the processes that are using that "file"( in unix systems all the serial devices are just files to read from). Try to use fuser to list the processes that use your file. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuser_(Unix)

In your case something like this:
$ fuser /dev/tty.my-device