# Identify COM ports via Python

Tags: python

I have my system (Windows) hooking several devices. So I have multiple COM ports, such like COM1,3,4,7,11...

My question is, how to identify which port is for which device via Python? i.e.How can I determine which connected device is the correct device to open a port to? If I get it down, I can talk to specific device I want.

So far, where I am is, I can list all the COM ports via Python, but what is next? My suspicion is, polling all serial devices?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090503/listing-available-com-ports-with-python?rq=1