# Loading variable from txt

Tags: python, database, error-handling, serial-port

I'm having problems with the following code:

```
f=open('config.txt')
lines=f.readlines()
print(lines[1])
print(lines[3])
print(lines[5])
print(lines[7])
print(lines[9])
print(lines[11])

#Import and define
import serial
import time
time.sleep(5)

#Settings
Port = lines[1]
TargetMaxVoltage = float(lines[3])
TargetStartVoltage = float(lines[5])
TargetIntervalVoltage = float(lines[7])
DelayTime = float(lines[9])
LogInterval = float(lines[11])
CV = True

ser = serial.Serial(Port, 9600)
TargetStartVoltageLock = TargetStartVoltage


#Starting Settings
ser.write(b'>Start\r\n')
ser.write(b'>VoSet 0.5\r\n')

time.sleep(1)

ser.write(b'>expMode 1\r\n')
ser.write(b'>runTime 1000000000\r\n')
ser.write(b'>stDly 1000000000\r\n')
ser.write(b'>IoSet 1\r\n')
ser.write(b'>Imax 50\r\n')
ser.write(b'>Imin 1\r\n')
ser.write(b'>FarEfc 1\r\n')
ser.write(b'>MolMax 9999\r\n')

LogTimeInterval = ">logIntv "+str(format(LogInterval, '.4f'))+"\r\n"
ser.write(LogTimeInterval.encode('utf-8'))

time.sleep(5)


#Running Method None CV Screening
while (TargetStartVoltage != TargetMaxVoltage and CV == False):
    DataSend = ">VoSet "+str(format(TargetStartVoltage, '.2f'))+"\r\n"
    print (DataSend)
    ser.write(DataSend.encode('utf-8'))
    TargetStartVoltage += TargetIntervalVoltage
    time.sleep(DelayTime)


#Running Method CV Screening
CVComplete = False
while (TargetStartVoltage <= TargetMaxVoltage and CV == True and CVComplete     != True):
    DataSend = ">VoSet "+str(format(TargetStartVoltage, '.2f'))+"\r\n"
    print (DataSend)
    ser.write(DataSend.encode('utf-8'))
    TargetStartVoltage += TargetIntervalVoltage
    time.sleep(DelayTime)
 else:
    TargetStartVoltage -= 2*TargetIntervalVoltage
    while(TargetStartVoltageLock <= TargetStartVoltage and CV == True and CVComplete != True):
        DataSend = ">VoSet "+str(format(TargetStartVoltage, '.2f'))+"\r\n"
        print (DataSend)
        ser.write(DataSend.encode('utf-8'))
        TargetStartVoltage -= TargetIntervalVoltage
        time.sleep(DelayTime)
    else:
        CVComplete = True

    ser.close()
```

And I get the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Mikkel\Desktop\Python Scripts\CV_and_Screeningv100.py", line
>   24, in 
>       ser = serial.Serial(Port, 9600)   File "C:\Users\Mikkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py",
>   line 31, in **init**
>       super(Serial, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Mikkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py",
>   line 182, in **init** self.open()   File
>   "C:\Users\Mikkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py",
>   line 62, in open raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}:
>   {!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
>   serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM11\n':
>   FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.',
>   None, 2)

I'm loading the data from a txt file called 'config.txt', and it seems that it is the

`Port = lines[1]`

or

```
ser = serial.Serial(Port,9600)
```

that are the problem. Am I using the wrong format? I tried to introduce a 'str', 'init' and 'float', but nothing works. The data on lines[1] is COM11, which is the current port.

Comment: You can't use `txt` lines directly, python will be auto sorted this. Add some identification string for every value. Like this : `Port#com11# `  and `a={e.split("#")[0]:e.split("#")[1]for e in lines}; ` can call `a["Port"]` as port_name.

Comment: And port definition show in `Device Manager` or can find manually . [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090503/listing-available-com-ports-with-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the Error log 
there is written can't open `COM11\n` so you have to remove the newline (`\n`).

Example: `Port.strip()`

Comment: Change answer for `lines = [e.strip() for e in lines]`