# use ft2232H on lattice machXO3 dev. board

Tags: python, fpga, lattice, ftdi

first sorry if this is a simple question but I can't figure this out. I have this [development board](http://www.latticesemi.com/en/Products/DevelopmentBoardsAndKits/MachXO3LStarterKit.aspx) and on page 19 on the kits [user guide](http://www.latticesemi.com/view_document?document_id=50873) the block diagram shows a RS232 line and on page 20 and 22 the schematic show the pins I need to connect to use RS232. My problem is that, despite being able to configure the fpga/cpld, I cannot find the com port on my computer (using pyserial and the following [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090503/listing-available-com-ports-with-python)(I tried changing COM%s in line 15 to FTUSB-%s)). So my questions are:

What interface does the FTDI, ft2232h USB to UART/FIFO,  chip use (Serial, parallel... ) on the computer's end (like arduino's virtual COM port)?

On lattice's software there are 3 options to program the device. the program shows the following: HW-USBN-2b (FTDI) (with port as FTUSB-0), HW-USBN-2b (with port as ezUSB-0) and HW-DLN-3C. How can I use either of them to communicate with the device outside of Lattice's software?

thanks for you time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) RS232 is a combination of UART with certain voltage levels for the high and low (i.e. +3 to +15V and -3 to -15V afaik. Never ever connect a RS232 adapter to standard 3.3V  or 5V devices e.g. UART, TTL-UART etc. The Lattice Semiconductor document just plainly missuses the term RS232 - try not to fall for it (IMHO the performance of their products strongly anticorrelates with the quality of their documentation and support).

2) page 19 of the linked doc shows the sections: Ordering Information, Technical Support Assistance, Revision History. Shifted by one page?

3) The FT2232H can be used in multiple modes. This depends on the way how it is addressed and of the settings flashed to the EEPROM connected to it (on the dev board is one placed but the FT2232H can be used without as well). The dev board is in the standard configuration designed to be programmed via the JTAG pins and the FT2232H is opened via the D2XX driver by lattice diamond. For that reason they flashed the EEPROM with settings which prohibits the use as virtual com port. The FTDI flash software can be used to change that behavior - for each bank seperately.

4) The solder bridges can be used to rearrange the connections (e.g. if one wants to change from the JTAG interface to the SPI or I2C programming interface). In your case you most likely want to place bridges on R14 and R15 to make the proper connection for an UART link to the port B of the FT2232H. EDIT: *This way Port A can be used in JTAG mode to program the FT2232H and port B to communicate via e.g. UART or even other modes like the fast opto or the parallel bus/FIFO - if the correct bridges are soldered. Changing the EEPROM settings might be still required to make Port B visible as VCP if one want to avoid the usage of the D2XXX driver*.

Comment: 1) thanks, but I already fell for it lol. how would you suggest that I send data to and from the fpga? I ask because I was considering one of those ttl-uart usb adpter.

Comment: 2) yes its page 20 sorry all pages are one off.

3) thanks, I was considering removing the driver but I imagine it would be a hassle.

4) I don't think I'll change this because I am only interested in communication between the computer and the fpga and from what I understood using the built-in FT2232H isn't really viable.

Comment: @user169808 the FT2232H is perfectly fine for "parallel" programming (port A) and communication (port B). See edit for details (tried to clarify that).

Comment: thanks, I think I understood now. I'll into programming the ftdi chip on the datasheet and site because I've never done this before.

Answer (score 1):

Most things were said in the previous reply, but here again in a slightly different way. This is what you need to prepare the use of an UART connection to the FPGA, but still needs any generic UART module configured into the FPGA after that:

This was tested on the Lattice MachXO3D development board, but I crosschecked that at least this part with the pins is the same with the MachXO3L board that you linked:
First, you need to bridge (solder) resistors R14 and R15 to connect UART RX and TX pins from the FTDI to the FPGA. You can use 0 Ohm resistors or just do it with solder tin, they are close enough for that. After that, FPGA pins/sites C11(=Tx) and A11(=Rx) can be used for your UART inside the FPGA, that you probably have as a Verilog/VHDL design. You find this information by looking at the "Appendix A. Schematics" of the user guide.

Additionally, something that was at least needed for the MachXO3D is to reconfigure the FTDI chip with FTDI's "ftprog" software. Not sure if it is needed for the MachXO3L, but it is easy to check and causes no harm:
Run "ftprog". Search/Parse for your FTDI chip and find the configuration for "Port B", and change "Hardware" from "245 FIFO" to "RS232 UART", and "Driver" from "D2XX" to "Virtual COM port". Then the second of the two ports you get from the FTDI chip (COM# in Windows, /dev/ttyUSB# in Linux; # being a number) should be usable through some virtual terminal software, use with python-serial, etc.

In Linux, the ftdi_sio kernel module has to be unloaded (sudo modprobe -r ftdi_sio) for Lattice Diamond to be able to program the FPGA, and after that loaded again (sudo modprobe ftdi_sio), to be able to use the respective /dev/ttyUSB# device. In Windows it doesn't need that and just works with python using COM#. Any suggestion to make this easier in Linux is also welcome!

In any case, as already said, you still need the respective UART module programmed in the FPGA and connected to the respective sites to be able to use it.

Update: I found that at a very obscure location, Lattice also documented a part of this, which is the User Guide to their Propel SDK. You can find the information starting Page 39 there: [Lattice Propel SDK 2.0 User Guide](https://www.latticesemi.com/view_document?document_id=53222)