# How to read Serial port/ Com port numbers in windows using Python?

Tags: python, windows, serial-port

I need to determine number of COM ports connected to my Windows computer and also to read the COM port number assigned to them. How can I do this using python?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205383/listing-serial-com-ports-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205383/listing-serial-com-ports-on-windows) seems very close to your question. Different opinions are provided by different users.

You can try to have a look at [pySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/examples.html#finding-serial-ports). Also, you can create a program that tries to read the serial ports info from the windows registry. Here is one more [interesting post](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/07/31/listing-all-serial-ports-on-windows-with-python/) that might prove helpful.