# How to determine if a machine physically has a serial port?

Tags: delphi, hardware, serial-port

I could try to open it, but if it is use by another program I will get an error and I need to be able to distinguish that case from the case where the machine physically has no serial port.

Any idea?

Comment: By peeping into the back of the machine :)

Comment: Back in good old days I could have used PEEK()  +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use WMI. Have a look at my [old post](http://sergworks.wordpress.com/2009/12/23/wmi-in-delphi-how-to-enumerate-serial-ports-and-everything-in-windows/)

Comment: +1 That looks great. I'll go to lunch, come back & code it then award the answer if it works (and I am sure that it will).  Thanks

Comment: the Win32_SerialPort doesn't contain any USB serial ports (as RRUZ hinted)

Answer (score 8):

Just for complement the Serg answer, the [`Win32_SerialPort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class used in [this](http://sergworks.wordpress.com/2009/12/23/wmi-in-delphi-how-to-enumerate-serial-ports-and-everything-in-windows/) article reports the physical com ports, if you wanna enumerate all the serial ports including the `USB-Serial/COM`  ports, you must use the `MSSerial_PortName`  class located in the `root\wmi` namespace.

```
uses
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj,
  Variants;

// Serial Port Name

procedure  GetMSSerial_PortNameInfo;
const
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;
begin;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer('localhost', 'root\WMI', '', '');
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM MSSerial_PortName','WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 do
  begin
    Writeln(Format('Active          %s',[FWbemObject.Active]));// Boolean
    Writeln(Format('InstanceName    %s',[FWbemObject.InstanceName]));// String
    Writeln(Format('PortName        %s',[FWbemObject.PortName]));// String

    Writeln('');
    FWbemObject:=Unassigned;
  end;
end;


begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      GetMSSerial_PortNameInfo;
      Readln;
    finally
    CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:Exception do
    begin
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
        Readln;
    end;
  end;
end.
```

for additional info about the serial ports try the classes located in the same namespace

- `MSSerial_CommInfo`
- `MSSerial_CommProperties`
- `MSSerial_HardwareConfiguration`
- `MSSerial_PerformanceInformation`

Answer (score 2):

You could also read from registry:
[Enumerating a List of systems Com Ports in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613166/enumerating-a-list-of-systems-com-ports-in-delphi)